# how to get key and value deep inside json tree

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson API. i have json as follows:

```
{
"rootNode": {
    "node1": "asdf",
    "banner": {
        "someElement": {
            "banner": {
                "innerNode": "asdf"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In this as you can see i have banner more than once. I need to get all the banner keys which exists deep inside. I am able to get the banner keys using following:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodeIterator =  rootNode.get("banner").fields();

while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {

   Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>) nodeIterator.next();

   logger.info("key --> " + entry.getKey() + " value-->" +   entry.getValue());
}
```

In this I have to iterate each node which is not very convenient solution. Can you please provide better solution or using recursion for this.

Comment: I dont think you have any other way.

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt to solve this using recursion.  Hint: this is not a free coding service.